# Заставить философов обедать правильно

Tags: rust

Нашел в документации [пример "обедающих философов"](http://rurust.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/dining-philosophers.html):

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

struct Philosopher {
    name: String,
    left: usize,
    right: usize,
}

impl Philosopher {
    fn new(name: &str, left: usize, right: usize) -> Philosopher {
        Philosopher {
            name: name.to_string(),
            left: left,
            right: right,
        }
    }

    fn eat(&self, table: &Table) {
        let _left = table.forks[self.left].lock().unwrap();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(150));
        let _right = table.forks[self.right].lock().unwrap();
        println!("{} начала есть.", self.name);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!("{} закончила есть.", self.name);
    }
}

struct Table {
    forks: Vec<Mutex<()>>,
}

fn main() {
    let table = Arc::new(Table { forks: vec![
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
    ]});

    let philosophers = vec![
        Philosopher::new("Джудит Батлер", 0, 1),
        Philosopher::new("Рая Дунаевская", 1, 2),
        Philosopher::new("Зарубина Наталья", 2, 3),
        Philosopher::new("Эмма Гольдман", 3, 4),
        Philosopher::new("Анна Шмидт", 0, 4),
    ];

    let handles: Vec<_> = philosophers.into_iter().map(|p| {
        let table = table.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            p.eat(&table);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Использую компилятор v.1.25 под FreeBSD 11.1. Все успешно собирается и исполняется. Только одно "но" - "философы" обедают последовательно, а не параллельно. На всякий случай попробовал этот же пример выполнить в онлайн-среде [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org). Работает так же неправильно!

Что я делаю не так? Что нужно изменить, чтобы пример заработал правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому, что пример - упрощенный и мутексы плохие.
Нужно добавить случайное время. И еще, если философ взял одну вилку - но не может взять другую, то он должен положить вилку, чтобы не держать соседа.

вообще, задача обсуждалась уже, в гугле "обедающие философы rust" и там найдете на форуме (не уверен, что тут ссылки разрешены)